# Convert JavaScript Date to MS JSON Format

Tags: javascript, time

I have a date in milliseconds (e.g. 1315166400000) and I need to convert it to the MS JSON format (e.g. /Date(1315166400000+0400)/). The problem is in timezone.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about that format but it's not JSON.

Comment: What's `MS JSON`?  What's the problem with the timezone, what's wrong with it?

Comment: You can use `( new Date ).getTimezoneOffset()` to get the offset (of the local machine) in minutes...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getTimezoneOffset()` to get the difference between local and GMT time: [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: Some useful documentation instead: [getTimeZoneOffset() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: -1 For referencing **terrible documentation**. It would be the opposite if you would reference some **reliable** source such as Mozilla Developer Network.